# Make the tkinter gui update live

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm making a Bitcoin price GUI. And I was wondering, is there any way to make the price update live?

```
page = urllib.request.urlopen("https://www.coindesk.com/price/bitcoin").read()
html = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
btcClass = html.find(class_="price-large")
btcClass1 = str(f"{btcClass}$")
btcClass2 = btcClass1[54:63]
Label1 = tkinter.Label(text=f"BTC\n{btcClass2}", font=("Arial", 25)).pack()

def Update():
    #price update

Update()
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the `.after()` method.

```py
def Update(
     ... code that gets prices and updates screen)
     root.after(1000, Update)
```

this will update your screen every 1000ms (1 second)

```py
Update():
      html = BeautifulSoup(page, "html.parser")
      btcClass = html.find(class_="price-large")
      btcClass1 = str(f"{btcClass}$")
      btcClass2 = btcClass1[54:63]
      label.config(text=f"BTC\n{btcClass2}"
      root.after(1000, Update)
```